# Permission errors in setting up Git

Tags: git, permissions, ssh, git-bash

#### Background

I have a Linode VPS (Ubuntu 12.04 server), and I want to use Git to manage my files from the VPS to my local Windows desktop.

I have installed Git Bash and have been using that on the Windows/local end of things.

I continue to get the error:

```
 Fatal: Could not read from remote repository
 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
 and the repository exists.
```

when I attempt to push a remote repo I've added.

Can someone double check my process, and tell me exactly what is needed for proper access rights?

#### Repository setup

First, I created a `git` user, and put them in a group called `gitgroup`. I've put in SSH keys and can login without a password to `git@server.domain.com`

I would like to keep my repo in `/srv/git/`, so I created a directory `/srv/git/myrepo`.

Inside the directory, I ran the command `git init --bare`.

On my local computer, I created a directory called `git-local`, and ran `git init` in it. It says it is the master repo.

So now I pull up Git Bash in my `git-local` directory. I attempt to add a remote repo:

```
$ git remote add myrepo git@server.domain.com:/srv/git/myrepo/
```

This works without error.

I created earlier an HTML file and added it to my master local repo.

I tell Git to push the changes:

```
$ git push myrepo master
```

This returns the error I've outlined above.

#### Permissions

The user `git` is the owner and creator of `/srv/var/git/myrepo`.
The group `gitgroup` is the owner of `/srv/var/git` (was created by `root`).

What am I missing?

Comment: yep sorry about that. I'm obviously using my actual server host name, and my actual domain name.

Comment: What are the exact permissions on that directory? Do all parents have the *relevant* x (execute) bit set for the user `git` or the group `gitgroup`, whichever applies? (You may want to post the permissions of these directories here — i.e., run `ls -ld /srv /srv/var /srv/var/git /srv/var/git/myrepo` and post the output — so we can validate them.) Last, does `git push --verbose` yield more info?

Answer (score 3):

This [solution](http://easy-develop.net/Git:solved) helped me:

```
cd ~/.ssh
chmod 600 *
```